# Angular 7 Bootstrap 4 sidebar

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular7

It is possible to create Bootstrap 4 sidebar with sub menus in Angular 7,something like [this](https://www.codeply.com/go/GQ1Mz8RqZB/bootstrap-4-sidebar-menu-(toggleable))

thanks

Comment: You can use Bootstrap in Angular, yes.

Comment: That link is Bootstrap sidebar, just add it in your angular 7 project and it will be bootstrap 4 sidebar with angular 7 :D

Comment: Hi,If I add it will not work because there is no jQuery

Answer (score 4):

I use this:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples

You can nest the accordion several levels deep in the exposed panes to get the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! It possible with bootstrap and you can also use Angular material for side nav which is easy and modern approach.

Comment: +1. Here's the link to the Angular material [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview)